# Is there an easy way to search for Non-English movie question in this community?

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried searching for questions about Non-English movies on this site but couldn't find anything apart from Indian movies. I am Indian so can identify them more easily. But searching for "French", "Japanese" "Chinese" etc. returned mostly the results about characters of those ethnicity in English language movies.

I see that there is a korean-cinema & japanese-cinema tag as well as indian-cinema tag. But the tag wiki suggest to not use it if the question is about a specific movie in that language.

So, I was just wondering, how can I get a list of all (most) of the question about non-english movies with minimal search?

Also as a followup question, should we tag non-english movies as such so that they are easily found? Using maybe "foreign-language" tag.

Comment: Lots of previous questions in this area .... https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=foreign

Comment: @iandotkelly the discussion seems to be a long time ago (>3y) & mostly centered around tagging country of origin for identification questions. In any case, with Netflix & Amazon, I now have access to more n more non-english movies through English subs. The discussion/answer I want is whether to tag every plot-explaination non-english movies into a bunch for easy search

Comment: As to your last question, I'm afraid that's not how we use tags on this site. Tags describe the question, not the film the question is about.